# Windows 10 Store apps not working - The application was unable to start correctly

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

When I try to run one of the Windows 10 pre-installed Store apps, or indeed the Store app itself, I get the following error message and the application won't run:

> Activation of application Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> failed with error:
>
> {Application Error} The application was unable to
> start correctly (0x%lx). Click OK to close the application.

Other error messages which show up in the Event Viewer are:

under AppModel-Runtime:

> 0x23F: Cannot create the process for package
> Microsoft.WindowsStore_11602.1.26.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe because an
> error was encountered while performing the integrity check.
> {Application Error}
>
> The application was unable to start correctly
> (0x%lx). Click OK to close the application.

and under DistributedCOM:

```
Unable to start a DCOM Server: App as Unavailable/Unavailable. The error:
"575"
Happened while starting this command:
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_11602.1.26.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WinStore.Mobile.exe" -ServerName:App.AppXqagq4n4gvy0tjw576pgh6xr601s1h1mv.mca
```

Standard applications work fine, only Store apps are affected. I cannot think of any changes I've done to the system lately that could have affected it. I've made sure I've got all Windows updates installed.

Comment: What Windows 10 build are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound 10.0.10586 Build 10586. Home edition.

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but I've just disabled it for a test and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

MS released a tool that's supposed to help fix windows 10 store issues, you could try run it and see here's the address:
https://solutions.diagnostics.support.microsoft.com/run/6b089dc3-50d6-4add-9959-337fca72c533#

Comment: Well, it definitely did something. Now rather than get an error, I can see the frame of the window of the app for a fraction of a second before it crashes without a message. Oh, and my desktop wallpaper's gone, for some reason.

Comment: I forgot to say it errored with the same error message 'The application was unable to start correctly'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error (though `"2147942402"`, which is `"File not found"`) when trying to run several Microsoft Store `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` applications.

- Maybe coincidentally, but the issue was resolved after running: Component Services `comexp.msc`
- There expand `Console Root->Component Services->Computers->My Computer`
- Right-click `My Computer`
- Properties
- `Default Properties` tab
- You will probably see the option `Enable Distributed COM on this computer` enabled. Uncheck it (temporarily)
- Apply
- If you see a warning message confirm with `Yes`
- OK
- Open Properties and re-enable the just disabled option

This as it seems shouldn't change anything, but possibly some other settings get reset with disabling and re-enabling and so the applications started to work for me again.